# Is LTE radiation stronger when there is no reception

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, radiation, biophysics, microwaves

I am connecting to the internet with the tethering option on my phone.
I wonder if the LTE radiation is stronger when there is no connection.

Comment: You are exposed to radiation 24/7 and it is not harmful. You shouldn't be worried about it.

Comment: I vote for wrapping the phone (or yourself) in tin foil.

Comment: Please define acronyms the first time you use them.   What is LTE?

Comment: haha... I thought LTE was a physics/pseudo physics term term...was a bit stumped.

Comment: I'm probably more likely than most here to be concerned about radiation - this is where some back of the envelope calculations are essential.  Whether or not you have wifi, you are bathed 24/7 in (EM) radiation.   The crucial questions are what frequencies and what dose is harmful.  The former is easy to answer, the latter, in some sense, unanswerable.

Answer (score 1):

[International Agency for Research on Cancer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Agency_for_Research_on_Cancer) groups cell phone in group 2B, which is for possibly carcinogenic to humans. Not even probably. So, it is not that harmful .

But, you can protect your by [Electromagnetic shielding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_shielding). You can figure out a way to connect conductive or magnetic materials either to your or the phone, but if you connect it to your phone, there might be network interference which lead 'no network' thing and anyone won't be able to call you.

If you want to know more about it, just add comments. I will answer it even if I die.